# Decimal conversion from vb.net to store in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, parsing, localization, decimal

I have this piece of code

```
Dim lt As Decimal
Dim lg As Decimal
Decimal.TryParse(tbLat.Value.Replace(".", ","), lt)
Decimal.TryParse(tbLng.Value.Replace(".", ","), lg)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("latitude", lt)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("longtitude", lg)
```

in which I am trying to store the `lt` and `lg` parameters in column `decimal(9,6)`.

In the local SQL Server it worked fine, but when I deployed in to my web server it gave me this error

> *Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. The statement has been terminated.*

I decided to increase the precision to 16 so the column became `decimal(16,6)`. Now it stores the whole number like that 25252525.000000!

Probably is matter of localize, but my question is how to avoid localization and store the number safely?

Comment: yes, tbLat and tbLng are <asp:HiddenField>

Comment: It stored the number as `25252525.000000`.  What should it have looked like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, after googling and trying I follow the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx and that drives me in the code:

```
            Dim style As NumberStyles = NumberStyles.Number Or NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol
            Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")
            Dim lt As Decimal
            Dim lg As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(tbLat.Value, style, culture, lt) Then
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("latitude", lt)
            End If
            If Decimal.TryParse(tbLng.Value, style, culture, lg) Then
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("longtitude", lg)
            End If
```

which worked in both local and web.
Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are losing the decimal place at some point in the process.

Without knowing more about your locale, I would suggest removing the replacement of "." with "," and just parsing the decimal values in the default way:

```
Dim lt As Decimal
Dim lg As Decimal
If (Decimal.TryParse(tbLat.Value, lt)) And (Decimal.TryParse(tbLng.Value, lg)) Then
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("latitude", lt)
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("longtitude", lg)
Else
   'Display Error
End If
```

If that doesn't work you should do some debugging and examine `tbLat.Value`, `tbLng.Value`, `lt`, `lg`, and `com.Parameters` collection to see where the conversion is failing.

From there if you are using MS SQL you can use SQL Server Profiler to see what values are passed to SQL.  You should be able to see where the decimal place is being lost and either fix it directly or update your question here.

Comment: thanks for your answer pseudocoder. I started from tbLat.Value but that gave me the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. The statement has been terminated." So I replaced the point symbol and works localy. When I deployed the project tha same error comes in web. Now I am looking for the safest way to bypass these kind of errors

Comment: That being the case, it sounds like this is definitely a localization issue, and unfortunately I don't have experience in that area.  I would suggest posting information about what version of IIS and SQL you are using both locally and for production, and what locale each server is in.